# CATransformLayer touch events handling

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, calayer, catransformlayer

I have searched over the internet and Stackoverflow but i couldn't find any answer to this specific question, So here's my question,

I'm trying to create a double sided `UIView` which responds to touch events both sides(Such as UIButton, UISwitch, etc...). I have achieved that by adding two distinct `CALayer`s to `CATransformLayer`. All works good but touches doesn't responds to the ui elements added from interface builder. To replicate the problem, i have created an `UIView` in the nib(frontView) added all ui elements from interface builder and add that `UIView` reference to `CATransformLayer` and all works good except it doesn't respond to touch events.

I understand that `CALayer` or `CATransformLayer` doesn't inherits from `UIResponder` class like `UIView`. And i believe there is a way to bring this layer to responder chain but i'm wondering how?. Below is my simplified problem code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CATransformLayer *myLayer = [[CATransformLayer alloc] initWithLayer:self.view.layer];
    myLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
    [myLayer addSublayer:frontView.layer];//Here 'frontView' is a reference to UIView from nib file
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
}
```

Any support will greatly appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The doc says: "The hitTest: method should never be called on a transform layer as they do not have a 2D coordinate space into which the point can be mapped."